# c# colorpicker and loading

Tags: c#, colors, picker

I have got a colorpicker to save a user selection as a text file, and the color then gets loaded at program startup. The problem is I am using .toknowncolor(); which is fine, but there are some colours in the colorpicker swatch that it doesn't like - so it will be fine with say black/white/yellow/red/blue/etc - the basic colours, but when it starts going into different shades of a colour, it doesn't like it. I am assuming this is because its not a known color. I have tried the other 2 options (toargb() + tostring()) but I can't get them to work. Here is what I have;

```
//In my linklabel
private void TextCol_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog TextColour = new ColorDialog();
            TextColour.AllowFullOpen = false;
            TextColour.ShowHelp = true;
            if (TextColour.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                #region Labels
                label1.ForeColor = TextColour.Color;
              if (Customise == true)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("C:/BMW/Colours/TextCol.txt", TextColour.Color.ToKnownColor() + "");
                }
            }
        }

//At the top
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InvoiceSavePath.Text = File.ReadAllText("C:/BMW/Invoice Save Path.txt");
        string[] TextCol = File.ReadAllLines("C:/BMW/Colours/TextCol.txt");
        label1.ForeColor = Color.FromName(TextCol[0]);
    }
```

So a user changes the colour with the linklabel, it writes it to the txt file, then loads it again on next startup. Works perfectly with basic colors, but not with others - how can I make it work with all the swatch colors - I am not wanting to use the custom color option...standard swatch will do :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ARGB functions.

To write:

```
File.WriteAllText("C:/BMW/Colours/TextCol.txt", TextColour.Color.ToArgb().ToString());
```

To read / parse:

```
label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(Int.Parse(TextCol[0]));
```